# How can I set a object tag in the xib with Xcode 4?

Tags: iphone, ios, tags

How can I set a object tag in the xib with Xcode 4 ?

Thanks, Niels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the object inspector (the one that looks like a slider thumb, in the right-side panel), scroll down to the bottom. There'll be a "Tag" field.

Comment: Thanks I've been looking right here for the last 30 minutes, but my vision seems to be going down...